# Measure performance of DB2 view

Tags: db2, db2-400

I am trying to compare the performance of a view before and after adding an index. So I am trying to measure the performance of it using below query:

```
create table qtemp.ffs as (select * from psavlldsvw) with data   
Statement ran successfully   (1,932 ms  =  1.932 sec)
```

Above statement is what I have used where psavlldsvw is the view name.

As you might guess, the idea is to measure how much time the above query takes to complete in both cases.

Can I please get some feedback on how good this method is for comparison?

Comment: "how well a DB2 view is performing" in terms of what? Isn't a view just a SELECT statement? And would not additional predicates be applied to the view / statement? BTW: What platform and version of Db2?

Comment: In terms of the execution time. This is the latest version of DB2 for IBMi

Comment: The test might be meaningless, depending on the view definition (i.e. does the view query multiple tables and use multiple predicates?). The approach you should use is to use the Visual Explain tool to assess the performance of __queries__ that reference the view, to verify they are using the best possible indexed access plan etc.

Answer (score 0):

The test is indeed meaningless...

First of all the question is poorly worded, you can not and are not testing a view.  Views are performance neutral on Db2 for i.

Running a statement, adding an index and rerunning the statement is a meaningless test.  Db2 for i has all kinds tricks built in to improve the speed of a repeated statement. Among them

- Input data cached in memory
- Data access paths are left open

Starting from a fresh connection, you can ensure that no data is in memory by using `SETOBJACC OBJ(YOURLIB/YOURFILE) OBJTYPE(*FILE) POOL(*PURGE)` for each table referenced by your statement.

Now run the statement multiple times; at least 3 if the system defaults have not been changed.  You should see that the first (few) iterations is slower than the last few.  This is a result of the data access path being left open for a repeated statement.

Now add your index, disconnect/reconnect, clear the object(s) from memory and run your tests again.

Depending on the use case for the statement, you may want to focus on the first iteration performance or the later iterations.

Mao is correct in that using Visual Explain (VE) is the best way to see if an index is being used or otherwise understanding how the query is performing.

Lastly realize that load on the server effects how the query engine operates.  The query engine optimizer will calculate your jobs "fair share" of memory and that value will affect rather or not some more efficient yet memory intensive plans would be used. So if you're testing in a non-prod environment that doesn't exactly match prod in terms of resources, data size and load, the results are likely to differ when the query is moved to prod.

Performance tuning is part art, part science.  Generally, use VE to ensure that you've got a decent query to start with.  Then monitor actual production use to ensure that it's preforming as expected.

Comment: You need to re-read the question. you have miserably failed to understand it.

Comment: @theju112t in addition to reading the editing answer I suggest you spend some time reading [Database performance and query optimization](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=database-performance-query-optimization)

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed answer sir. I have the VE tool but I am just finding it difficult to understand the expensive operations. Do you have reference to any VE guide that I can use.

Comment: Check out the VE `View` menu, in particular the `Highlighting` and `Arrow Label` icons.